# Best way to store empty kegs

Tags: kegging, sanitation

After using, then cleaning a keg with PBW, what is the best way to store the cleaned keg?  I may not use the keg for a while, and I would like to avoid mold growing in any residual water (for example).

Should I: sanitize after cleaning? store with the lid off to encourage drying? something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After cleaning (I use PBW also, occasionally Oxiclean) I turn the keg upside down and let it dry overnight.  Then I put the lid on and pressurize to 10 psi.  That serves 2 purposes. First, the CO2 helps prevent things from growing in the keg. Second, when I'm ready to use the keg, I pull the pressure relief valve.  If there's not still pressure on the keg, I know that it's leaky and needs to be repaired before I use it.

Comment: I like the pressure-testing technique!

Comment: Do you also purge the keg with CO2?

Comment: When I fill it, yes.  But I store it with CO2 in it, as I said in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask whether you purge the keg of air before pressurizing and storing it.

Comment: Nope, not necessary since there's nothing in there to make me worry about oxidation.